# Converting day of week from integer to character string in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains days of the week of events as numbers (1-7, 1 is Monday...7 is Sunday). I've converted it to the days of the week that a user would understand (Monday, Tuesday, etc) by just replacing every instance of 1 with Monday (etc) in that row. Is there a library that would do this for me more cleanly?

Answer (score 3):

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(1:7, 20, TRUE)
#[1] 7 7 3 6 5 4 6 1 5 5 4 6 7 2 4 7 7 1 4 4
y <- factor(x, labels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", 
                          "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
                          "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"),
            ordered = TRUE)
# [1] Sunday    Sunday    Wednesday Saturday  Friday    Thursday  Saturday  Monday    Friday    Friday    Thursday  Saturday  Sunday   
#[14] Tuesday   Thursday  Sunday    Sunday    Monday    Thursday  Thursday 
#Levels: Monday < Tuesday < Wednesday < Thursday < Friday < Saturday < Sunday
```

Omit `ordered = TRUE` if you don't want an ordered factor and use `as.character` if you need a character vector. If you need the latter, you could also do this:

```
c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")[x]
```

Comment: DIdn't see your full post before i posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(chron)
days = sample(1:7, 10, replace = TRUE)

weekdays(days + 3, abbreviate = FALSE)
```

Indexed from Friday so `+3` sets the the index as Monday. The output is an ordered factor which is nice for plotting purposes.

Comment: That's not how the `weekdays` function works. Is that a different function from some package?

Comment: Oops, masked by `lubridate` - my bad.

Comment: Okay apparently it was from a library called `chron`. No idea how that got in there.. Thanks

Comment: Yeah - just checked it now to make sure on a clean environment

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore, `Error: 'weekdays' is not an exported object from 'namespace:chron'`. :(